# R a plot ploblem with lines?

Tags: r, plot

I have to do some plots using R. I run R-studio and I have used multiple R distros in order to check if the same problem is preented.
The problem is that the `plot()` with `type='l'` connects all points together. Can somebody help?

```r
p <- sample(seq(0,2,0.01), 100, replace = T)
plot(p, p^2, type='l', col=2)
```

[image]

Comment: It doesn't connect *all* points together, it connects them in sequence, (p[1], p²[1]) to (p[2], p²[2]), etc. Can you make the question more clear?

Comment: It may be useful to only look at the points, instead of a line such as: `plot(p, p^2, type='p', col=2)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll probably have to `sort` the points first.

```
p <- sort(sample(seq(0, 2, 0.01), 100, replace=TRUE))
plot(p, p^2, type='l', col=2)
```

[image]